# How to get the solution of "f = λn . if (n = 0) then 0 else (2 + (f (n − 1))) end"?

Tags: algorithm, math

《Design concepts in programming languages》chapter 5,"fix point",page 165:

```
f = λn . if (n = 0) then 0 else (2 + (f (n − 1))) end
```

use this example to show that a function can be a solution of a equation as a fix point,the solution of this equation is:

```
f(x）=2x
```

the book seems not tell how to got this solution,it tells only get it by "intuitively",then test it's the right solution

I want to know the "procedure" of how to got the solution:f(x)=2x

1 there is the procedure,it's...

2 it have proved that there is no solution,man can't do it,can only guess the solution

3 there is a procedure,but we have found it yet

Thanks!

Comment: If your intuition doesn't yet work well enough, you can compute f(i) for small i, and see if you can figure it out

Comment: The "procedure" is the same as mathematical thinking - there's common tricks (like computing or solving small cases), but there's no "procedure" that works for all problems. In this case, rewriting in more familiar language (eg in the language of recurrence relations: F(0) = 0, F(n) = F(n-1) + 2)  might help.

Comment: 2x-2=0,I can got answer by intuition it's 1,but I can show the procedure:1 move -2 to right,got 2x=2;2 devision 2 on both side,then got x=1.so I can got it by intuition,but if not use the intuition,only use the "rules",I can got the answer too(so the machine can do it,machine hanve no intuition).so is there some "rules",it I use it step by step ,I can got the answer f(x)=2x

Comment: yes," there's no "procedure" that works for all problems",and I want to know are the " there's no "procedure" that works for all problems" is a theorem?what is the name?

Comment: Yes, the procedure is called formal proof, but the "steps" are more complicated than rearranging terms, just as you can't solve recurrence relations by re-arranging them using simple identities like you used to prove "2x-2=0" is the same as "x=1".

Comment: Automatically showing two programs are equivalent is impossible in general via the halting problem.

Comment: The difficulty you're encountering is very common when you start learning mathematics -- some proofs are presented with a necessary "guess" at the start, and what is often missed out is the part where the person making the proof first played around a lot with the problem, working out small cases, gaining intuition, trying various different guesses and that the final "guess" comes out of this process of playing around. This is just how maths is, and it's contrary to many people's expectations...

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute into the formula given.

If f(n) = cn:

f(0) = c.0 = 0, so okay

f(n) = cn = 2 + c ( n - 1 )

:: cn = 2 + cn - c

:: 0 = 2 - c

:: c = 2